# How to compare two files in python and get the values in Boolean?

Tags: python

I am new in python I am working on python file operations,In Which I have a two input files

**1.Security_Headers_list.txt**

```
9508,content-security-policy
9496,content-security-policy
9240,content-security-policy
904,content-security-policy,x-content-type-options,strict-transport-security,x-frame-options
8013,content-security-policy
5263,content-security-policy,x-frame-options
4378,content-security-policy
3854,content-security-policy
3331,content-security-policy
```

**2.Master.txt**

```
strict-transport-security
content-security-policy
x-frame-options
x-content-type-options
x-xss-protection
public-key-pins
```

**Security headers list has to be compared against the master list.**

**Script:**

```
    f_out=open('Output.txt', 'wb')
    f=open('master.txt','r')
    a=f.readlines()
    f1=open("Security_Headers_list.txt","r")
    b=f1.readlines()
    x=0
    str=""
    match =[]
    appno =""
    while x<len(a):
            h=a[x].strip()
            y=0
            z=0
            while y<len(b):
                    c=b[y].strip()
                    appno=b[0]
                    if (h==c):
                            z=1
                    y=y+1
            if z == 1:
                    str=str+"Yes,"
            else:
                    str=str+"No, "
            x=x+1
    match.insert(0,appno)
    f_out.write(b[0].rstrip() + "," + str[0:len(str)-2])
    f.close()
    f1.close()
    f_out.close()
```

**Output has to be like :**

```
9508,No,Yes,No,No,No,No
9496,No,Yes,No,No,No,No
9240,No,Yes,No,No,No,No
904,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No
8013,No,Yes,No,No,No,No
5263,No,Yes,Yes,No,No,No
4378,No,Yes,No,No,No,No
3854,No,Yes,No,No,No,No
3331,No,Yes,No,No,No,No
```

I had not got what I want , please give me some advice on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest slightly different use of joins than @ZdaR (+a generator expression):

```
with open("Master.txt", "r") as data1:
    master = data1.read().rstrip().split("\n")
with open("Security_Headers_list.txt", "r") as data2:
    for line in data2:
        num, cat = line.rstrip().split(",", 1)
        print num + '  ' + ', '.join('Yes' if t in cat else 'No' for t in master)
```

Comment: Perfect Indeed ! Thanks Antony !

Comment: i get the following output as                                                                9508  No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes
9496  No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes
9240  No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes
904  Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, No, No, Yes
8013  No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes
5263  No, Yes, Yes, No, No, No, Yes
4378  No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes
3854  No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes
3331  No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes
Not sure about the last value of "Yes" which came for each and every num !

Comment: fixed (added `rstrip()`)

Answer (score 1):

As you have 2 files so you need to extract data form one file, create a list of that data, which represents the types `types = data1.read().split("\n")`. Then you iterate over each line in the first file and look if the types are present in it or not and accordingly substituting the `"Yes"` or `"No"` values.

```
with open("Master.txt", "r") as data1, open("Security_Headers_list.txt", "r") as data2:
  types = data1.read().split("\n")
  for line in data2:
    out = ""
    split_line = line.strip().split(",")
    sno, categories = split_line[0], split_line[1:]
    out+=sno+"  "
    for typ in types:
      if typ in categories:
        out+="Yes, "
      else:
        out+="No, "
    print out[:-2]
```

Output:

```
9508  No, Yes, No, No, No, No
9496  No, Yes, No, No, No, No
9240  No, Yes, No, No, No, No
904  Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, No, No
8013  No, Yes, No, No, No, No
5263  No, Yes, Yes, No, No, No
4378  No, Yes, No, No, No, No
3854  No, Yes, No, No, No, No
3331  No, Yes, No, No, No, No
```

**EDIT:**

With the help of @AntonyHatchkins in the comments and list comprehension, the above code can be reduced to :

```
with open("TEKST_ny.txt", "r") as data1, open("sample.txt", "r") as data2:
  types = data1.read().split("\n")
  for line in data2:
    sno, categories = line.rstrip().split(',', 1)
    print "".join([sno+"  "]+["Yes, " if typ in categories else "No, " for typ in types ])[:-2]
```

Comment: `sno, categories = line.rstrip().split(',', 1)`

Comment: i get the following output as 9508 No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes 9496 No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes 9240 No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes 904 Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, No, No, Yes 8013 No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes 5263 No, Yes, Yes, No, No, No, Yes 4378 No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes 3854 No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes 3331 No, Yes, No, No, No, No, Yes                                                                                                        Not sure about the last value of "Yes" which came for each and every num !

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
f_out=open('Output.txt', 'wb')
f=open('master.txt','r')
a=f.readlines()
f1=open("Security_Headers_list.txt","r")
b=f1.readlines()
x=0
str=""
match =[]
for line in b:
    options = line.split(",")
    l = options[0]
    options1 =[]
    for opt in options:
        options1.append(opt.strip())
    for match in a:
        if match.strip() in options1:
            l = l + ",Yes"
        else:
            #print match.strip()
            l = l + ",No"
    f_out.write(l+"\n")
f.close()
f1.close()
f_out.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'filecmp' module to compare two files and it will return boolen value, true or false. It has easy syntax. Here is the link to help you out.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html